# Stuck in an if Statement, to check Numbers which are in a List

Tags: c++, loops

I´m new at C++, but i hope everyone gets the Problem.
So i making a List with Numbers, which can be store in that List. But everytime i want to check with a KeyState what is in my List it Loops all the way through.

```
cout << "Which Number do you want to Store?" << endl;
int newNum;
cin >> newNum;
numberContainer.push_front(newNum);

cout << "To Show Numbers you stored press N" << endl;
if (GetKeyState(0x4E))
{
    //Show all Numbers which are stored
    Dump();
}
```

And Thats my Dump Method

```
for (int i = 1; i < numberContainer.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Position: " << i;
        for (it = numberContainer.begin(); it != numberContainer.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << " stored Number: " << *it << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

And at the End i have a GameLoop Method, it has a While and in it the First Method where i store the Numbers

Answer (score 3):

`GetKeyState` is not blocking. So in your program the user must hit the key immediately after submitting the number. If the user fails to do so, the next number is prompted.

Maybe this gives you what you want:

```
cout << "Which Number do you want to Store?" << endl;
int newNum;
cin >> newNum;
numberContainer.push_front(newNum);

char key;
do {
    cout << "Enter 'N' to show the numbers you have stored or 'C' to continue     adding numbers." << flush;
    cin >> key;
    if (key == 'N') {
        //Show all Numbers which are stored
        Dump();
    }
} while (key != 'C');
```

Additionally I suggest you add some Quit option, like `if (key == 'Q') exitOuterLoop = true;`.

By the way, your `Dump()` function is completely wrong.

It outputs the first element of your container (size-1) times, because it loops from 1 to (size-1) and outputs the first element in the inner loop before unconditionally breaking out of the inner loop. It makes absolutely no sense.

I suppose it should look like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberContainer.size(); i++) {
    cout << "Position: " << (i+1)
         << " stored Number: " << numberContainer[i] << endl;
}
```

Or - in case your container does not support random access:

```
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (auto const & element : numberContainer) {
        ++i;
        cout << "Position: " << i
             << " stored Number: " << element << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that looks good. So in the While i put what ? In the Dump Method the size_t doesn't work. "No "[]" operator matches with this operand.

Comment: I don't know the type of your numberContainer - I just assumed it is a standard STL container. I cannot directly answer your question on "where to put what", because I don't know your overall code architecture. So I could be wrong with my guess. But I *think* you want to loop, until the user decides to stop entering numbers. So maybe pull the `char key;` to the front and wrap the rest into a `do { ...} while (key != 'Q');` where 'Q' stands for quit.

Comment: okay, i think i got it but the only thing that dont work is that when i confirm new numbers and let them show up he only gives me the first one i enter....so every number after that is not in the list

Comment: @Raycen I added an explaination why your Dump() function is wrong plus an additional solution that works with containers that do not support random access.